Subgraph with proxy upgradable contract
I have a smart contract for NFT marketplace and it is upgradable. This contract has some events and want to query this event thru subgraph. As my contract is proxy upgradable two contract is generated logic contract & proxy contract. Events are there in logic contract not proxy contract. In subgraph if I put proxy contract address then events will not be fetched in subgraph because it's ABI events are not defined it is in logic contract. If I put logic contract address then event would not be handled in subgraph as my marketplace would be run proxy contract as state to be kept. Here is my deploy.js. I have checked doc but did not find something.
const { ethers, upgrades } = require("hardhat");
const fs = require("fs");

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("Deploying contracts with account:", deployer.address);
  console.log("Account balance:", ethers.utils.formatEther(await deployer.getBalance()), "ETH");

  // Get the contract factory
  const Marketplace = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarketplace");

  // Estimate gas for deployment
  const deployTransaction = Marketplace.getDeployTransaction();
  const estimatedGas = await ethers.provider.estimateGas(deployTransaction);

  // Get the current gas price
   const gasprice = await ethers.provider.getGasPrice();

  console.log(`Estimated Gas: ${estimatedGas.toString()}`);
  console.log(`Gas Price: ${ethers.utils.formatUnits(gasprice, "gwei")} GWEI`);

  // Get the current nonce for the deployer address
  const nonce = await deployer.getTransactionCount();
  console.log(`Nonce: ${nonce}`);

  // Deploy proxy contract for NFTMarketplace with explicit initializer
  console.log("Deploying NFTMarketplace (Proxy)...");

  // Deploy proxy and pass arguments explicitly
    const marketplace = await upgrades.deployProxy(
        Marketplace, // Contract factory
        ["MyNFT", "MNFT", 2], // Arguments for NFTMarketplace.initialize
        { initializer: "initialize(string,string,uint256)" ,
           gasLimit: estimatedGas,
           gasPrice: gasprice,
           nonce: nonce
         } 
    );
  await marketplace.deployed();

  console.log("Marketplace Proxy deployed to:", marketplace.address);

  // Save ABI and Proxy address
  const data = {
    address: marketplace.address,
    abi: JSON.parse(marketplace.interface.format('json'))
  };

  fs.writeFileSync(
    '',
    JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
  );

  console.log("Marketplace contract info saved to Marketplace.json");
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

